# How to use PCSC Lite NPM library to interface with Smart Card?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, smartcard, apdu, pcsc

I am developing a website with React.js that needs to have smart card signing features. I am having trouble finding information on how to interface with a smart card. I know about PCSC and I can use the NPM library PCSC Lite to issue APDU commands to the card, however, I do not know what commands to issue to the card in order to acquire the certificate that is stored on the card. I have a way to authenticate the certificate on the backend and everything but I can not for the life of me figure out how to actually read the data off the card. Could anybody help me with this or even provide a resource where I can learn how to do this? I can't seem to find any good resources online that aren't confusing. I do know about ISO 7816 which has common commands in it and defines the structure of the APDU, however, I have tried using it to learn how to do this to no avail as it is too confusing for me to understand at this stage and I cannot seem to form commands that are able to interact with the smart card. It should also be worth noting that I am trying to interface with a government CAC card, however, I do not believe that the process for doing so is any different. Could someone please let me know how to do this? Or even if I have all this info wrong as I am very new to smartcards. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some notes, which don't fully answer the question:

- Smart cards are complicated and to an astonishing degree non-interoperable. Therefore you are likely to encounter contradicting information.
- CAC is a javacard-based specification, where standard commands from ISO 7816 parts -4, -8 and -9 don't help much. Select in mode 4 with given application ID should work, however. For more details I would search the CAC specification.
- If the contact interface is based on T=0 interface (I could not find a confirmation of this at a glance), LE handling is different. You receive a 61 xy response status for the command causing the response and have then to sent a GET RESPONSE with given xy value as P3 for retrieving the reponse data.